# Iterate through range and match values

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets: Week#, Events.

Sheet "Week#" (calendar week # in Column A and the start day of this week in Column B):

01  January 4, 2016

02  January 11, 2016

03  January 18, 2016

04  January 25, 2016

05  February 1, 2016

and so on till week 52

Sheet "Events" has next columns:

Facility, Repeats,  Belongs to week #,  Week # starts on,   Item,   Action, Status.

It's filled with something like this (number of rows varies):

SalonA, monthly, 4, January 25,2016, Floor, to mop the floor, Created

The script is like this:

```
function createEventmanually (title, date)
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
var EventStatus = sheet.getRange(row, 7).setValue("Created");
var title = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()+"  "+"Week "+sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue()+"   "+sheet.getRange(row,5).getValue()+":"+"  "+sheet.getRange(row,6).getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('RM') [0];
var date = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
var event = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date);
}
```

I manually copy and paste calendar dates from sheet Week# to column "Week # starts on" in sheet Events. And then run the script every time to create event.
How to automatize this process? I understand that it could be done through iteration but I cannot figure it out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is 52 calendar events (One every week) for every different
task in the Events sheet, this code is how you would need to do it.

```
function createAllEventsForTheYear() {
  var allRowsOfDataInEventSheet,allDataInWeekSheet,cal,eventSh,i,j,L,Lj,lastRowInEventSheet,lastRowInWeekSheet,
      lastColumnInEventSheet,lastColInWeekSh,ss,row,
      weekNumberSheet,rowDataBeingProcessedFromEventsSheet,thisEventTitle,thisWeeksDate;

  cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('RM')[0];
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  eventSh = ss.getSheetByName('Events');
  weekNumberSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Week#');

  lastRowInEventSheet = eventSh.getLastRow();
  lastRowInWeekSheet = weekNumberSheet.getLastRow();

  lastColumnInEventSheet = eventSh.getLastColumn();
  lastColInWeekSh = weekNumberSheet.getLastColumn();

  allRowsOfDataInEventSheet = eventSh.getRange(2, 1, lastRowInEventSheet-1, lastColumnInEventSheet).getValues();
  allDataInWeekSheet = weekNumberSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastColInWeekSh-1, lastColInWeekSh).getValues();

  L = allRowsOfDataInEventSheet.length;
  Lj = allDataInWeekSheet.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i+=1) { //Loop through every row of data in the Events sheet
    rowDataBeingProcessedFromEventsSheet = allRowsOfDataInEventSheet[i];//Get one row of data
    thisEventTitle = rowDataBeingProcessedFromEventsSheet[0] + "Week" + rowDataBeingProcessedFromEventsSheet[2] + "  " + rowDataBeingProcessedFromEventsSheet[4] + ":  " + rowDataBeingProcessedFromEventsSheet[5];

    for (j=0;j<Lj;j+=1) {//For every row in the Events sheet, create an event for every week of the year.  52 events for this event type
      thisWeeksDate = allDataInWeekSheet[j][1];//Get the date from the second column of the data in the Weeks# sheet
      cal.createAllDayEvent(thisEventTitle, thisWeeksDate);
    };

    eventSh.getRange(i+2, 7).setValue("Created");//I starts at 0, data starts on row 2
  };
};
```

I have not tested this, or even debugged it, so it may not run perfectly.

Comment: Sandy, the script works good. I just replaced lastColInWeekSh-1 to lastRowInWeekSheet-1 in line 19. Comments in lines were very useful: I'm not a programmer, but it's easier to understand the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  You can mark the answer as correct by clicking the big green check mark, if you wish, and up-vote if you want to.